# Why can't I kill nginx processes on Debian 5 Lenny server?

Tags: debian, nginx

I can't kill the nginx processes. There's something running with python:

```
python /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/producer.pyo --type=nginx
```

and master and worker processes and running. I don't know how to kill that.
see with this command `sudo ps -ef | grep -i nginx`

**Output:**

```
amer@stream14:/etc$ sudo ps -ef | grep -i nginx
root      3031     1  0 Oct27 ?        00:01:09 python /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/producer.pyo --type=nginx
root     16271 16254  0 May24 ?        00:00:00 supervise nginx-purge
www-data 17148     1  0 Oct27 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
www-data 17296     1  0 Oct27 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
www-data 17347     1  0 Oct27 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
www-data 18131     1  0 Oct26 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
www-data 20202     1  0 01:00 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
www-data 20256     1  0 01:01 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
www-data 20298     1  0 01:01 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
root     20989 16254  0 01:18 ?        00:00:00 supervise nginx
root     21048 20989  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx
www-data 21050 21048  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 21051 21048  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 21052 21048  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 21053 21048  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 21054 21048  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
www-data 21055 21048  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache loader process
root     21137 16254  0 01:20 ?        00:00:00 supervise accounting-nginx
root     21138 21137  3 01:20 ?        00:00:00 python /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/producer.pyo --type=nginx
amer     21143 17462  0 01:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) to supervise nginx. It's [not recommended](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule) in a production mode. To stop it, just down the nginx service:

```
# svc -d /path/to/nginx/service
```

or stop the `supervise` process:

```
# /etc/init.d/svscan stop
```

and turn on (or comment out) the `daemon` directive in Nginx configuration file.

Comment: From your linked `nginx` documentation: *"You can use `daemon off` safely in production mode with runit/daemontools, however you can't do a graceful upgrade. `master_process off` should never be used in production."*

Comment: Hi quanta, Its not working :(. 
i located nginx on: /usr/local/aflexi/etc/nginx
i tried to run daemontools commands but no use. This link did'nt help as well http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/8/3/debian-lenny-adding-an-nginx-init-script
now i'm getting frustrated because of it. please, any idea?

Comment: No. You need to find the location where nginx is started under daemontools (for e.g: `/service/nginx/run`). What is the output of `/etc/init.d/svscan stop`?